# How to convert an array of multiple entries into an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
const array = [['Team A', 'City A', '100'],['Team B', 'City A', '80'],['Team C', 'City A', '90']];
const map = array.map(x => {
  let output = {};
  output[x[0]] = {team: x[0], city: x[1], points: x[2]};
  return output
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(map));
```

And I'm getting output result as below

```
[{"Team A":{"team":"Team A","city":"City A","points":"100"}},
 {"Team B":{"team":"Team B","city":"City A","points":"80"}},
 {"Team C":{"team":"Team C","city":"City A","points":"90"}}]
```

And required out is

```
{"Team A": {"team": "Team A","city": "City A","points": "100"},
 "Team B": {"team": "Team B","city": "City A","points": "80"},
 "Team C": {"team": "Team C","city": "City A","points": "90"}}
```

Comment: Map returns an array and you want an object. So map is the wrong method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to make an object like this (`map` gives you an array):

```js
const array = [['Team A', 'City A', '100'],
               ['Team B', 'City A', '80'],
               ['Team C', 'City A', '90']];
const result = array.reduce((a, [team, city, points]) => {
  a[team] = {team, city, points};
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to several other answers, but without mutating data structures along the way:

```js
const restructure = (teams) =>
  teams .reduce ((a, [team, city, points]) => ({...a, [team]: {team, city, points}}), {})

const array = [['Team A', 'City A', '100'],['Team B', 'City A', '80'],['Team C', 'City A', '90']];

console .log (restructure (array))
```

This is far from the most performant code. An excellent article from [Rich Snapp](https://www.richsnapp.com/blog/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) explains why and how to fix it. But I personally would stick with this unless this becomes a bottleneck in my application.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.reduce` is going to loop through the original array and build a new object. We destructure the argument in order to quickly create our new key using the position of the data inside of the original array. Then we use the syntax `,` to say "assign the key, then return `tmp` variable"

```js
const format = [
  [
    'Team A',
    'City A',
    '100',
  ],
  [
    'Team B',
    'City A',
    '80',
  ],
  [
    'Team C',
    'City A',
    '90',
  ],
].reduce((tmp, [
  team,
  city,
  points,
]) => (tmp[team] = {
  team,
  city,
  points,
}, tmp), {});

console.log(format);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below snippet

```js
function mapArray(arr) {
   return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const [ team, city, points ] = curr;
    acc[team] = {
      team, city, points
    };
    return acc;
   }, {});
}

const array = [['Team A', 'City A', '100'],['Team B', 'City A', '80'],['Team C', 'City A', '90']];

console.log(mapArray(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised a simple [*for...of*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop isn't mentioned yet.

```js
const array = [['Team A', 'City A', '100'],['Team B', 'City A', '80'],['Team C', 'City A', '90']];

const output = {};
for (const [team, city, points] of array) {
  output[team] = {team, city, points};
}

console.log(output);
```

The reason why your current code doesn't work is because you call `array.map`, which by nature returns a new array, not an object. Furthermore you create a new `output` object in each `array.map` iteration, whereas there should only be one `output` object, holding the different teams.

Note that this answer makes use of [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the [ES2015 object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

Here is a version that is more similar to what you currently have, but uses [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This assigns `output` before iteration, updating `output` each iteration.

```js
const array = [['Team A', 'City A', '100'],['Team B', 'City A', '80'],['Team C', 'City A', '90']];

const output = {};
array.forEach(x => {
  output[x[0]] = {team: x[0], city: x[1], points: x[2]};
});

console.log(output);
```